# PrimeNG p-dropdown prevent onChange event

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, primeng

I am using the dropdown component of PrimeNG. In each option of the list, I am having an icon and with click on it, i want to call a method. Also, I need the onChange event of the dropdown to call another method.

The thing is, I somehow want to achieve, that the onChange event is never triggered, when the icon is clicked, although the option may have changed.

```
<p-dropdown 
  [options]="options"
  (onChange)="onOptionSelect($event.value)" 
 >
  <ng-template let-option pTemplate="item">
    <div>
      <div>{{option.value.value}}</div>
      <i class="pi pi-pencil" (click)="editOption(option.value)"></i>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
</p-dropdown>
```

Answer (score 0):

Update, found a way to fix it, I just pass the event in editOption and call Event.stopImmediatePropagation
:)